# Youtube don't stop to play audios

Tags: firefox, video, youtube

I would like to ask the community for help with a problem that is bothering me.
In my firefox 93.0 (64 bit), ubuntu 20.04.3, youtube doesn't stop playing audios, and videos, even when I have it paused or stopped. A few seconds after pausing (k key or any other command) the video or music starts playing again.
Even when I switch to another page, the audio from the previous page starts playing again, unless I start playing another video or music.

ystem Information
Manufacturer: LENOVO
Product Name: 80YH
Version: Lenovo ideapad 320-15IKB
Serial Number: PE03S1L7
UUID: 68a3de78-a148-11e8-0f88-641c679aecfc
Wake-up Type: Power Switch
SKU Number: LENOVO_MT_80YH_BU_idea_FM_ideapad 320-15IKB
Family: ideapad 320-15IKB

Comment: See if this occurs in both the Deb and Snap versions of Firefox. Then see if there is anything you can do to reproduce the issue in a 21.10 LiveUSB's "Try Ubuntu" environment. Then file a bug report detailing all the troubleshooting you did, and how a developer can reliably reproduce the problem in their test environment. If you can make this happen in the Firefox Snap, also comment in https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/feature-freeze-exception-seeding-the-official-firefox-snap-in-ubuntu-desktop/24210/160 and post a link to your bug report there.

Comment: @user535733 OP is using 20.04, which (by default) has the .deb version of firefox. Firefox snap is most likely not related to this question.

Comment: The troubleshooting method and bug reporting described is the same regardless of whether the user is using Deb or Snap.

Comment: The problem didn't happen when I used ubuntu, 20.04.3, through live usb.

Comment: @user535733 - Firefox 94.0.1 installed by the snap package, the problem remains the same when installing the .deb package. It doesn't happen with specific pages, but with all. If I go back to the "Home" page on Youtube, the audio from the video I was watching starts playing again. This doesn't happen when a new page is opened, firefox blocks autoplay, but after the first playback, the problem appears. Please, I need some guidance to make a bug report that can guide developers.

Comment: Guidance: The bug report goes to https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/home (you must create a login, sorry). The title of your bug should be something descriptive like: "YouTube videos do not stop playing when paused or stopped". The first paragraph of your bug should be exact, step-by-step instructions on how to reproduce the problem starting from a Ubuntu 21.10 LiveUSB's "Try Ubuntu" environment (older is less likely to be read) *Describing* the problem is less important than *reproducing* the problem. If they can reproduce it according to your instructions, the problem should smack them in the face

Comment: @user535733 - Thanks a lot. Bug has been reported in bugzilla.